# Code Horner’s Method for Polynomial Evaluation

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math

I am trying to code Horner’s Method for Polynomial Evaluation but for some reason its not working for me and I'm not sure where I am getting it wrong.

These are the data I have:

```
nodes = [-2, -1, 1]
x = 2
c (coefficients) = [-3, 3, -1]
```

The code I have so far is:

```matlab
function y = horner(x, nodes, c)

   n = length(c);
   y = c(1);

   for i = 2:n
       y = y * ((x - nodes(i - 1)) + c(i));
   end
end
```

I am supposed to end up with a polynomial such as `(−1)·(x+2)(x+1)+3·(x+2)−3·1` and if `x =2` then I am supposed to get `-3`. But for some reason I don't know where I am going wrong.

Edit:

So I changed my code. I think it works but I am not sure:

```
function y = horner(x, nodes, c)
   n = length(c);
   y = c(n);
   for k = n-1:-1:1
       y = c(k) + y * (x - nodes((n - k) + 1));
   end
end
```

Comment: Your second function (what you added by edit) isn't correct. It works only for x=2...

Comment: Can you explain what is each coefficient or node in the polynomial you expect to get? I didn't understand...

Comment: @Avi Apologies for not making it clear. The nodes are the data points. So for this example, the polynomial would be  c_1 + c_2(x - x_1) + c_3(x-x_1)(x-x_2). Each C corresponds to the coefficients and each x_i is the nodes (data points). So for this example, it would be (-1)*(x-x_1)(x-x_2) + 3*(x - x_1) - 3. However I need to write this using Horner's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
function y = horner(x, nodes, c)
   n = length(c);
   y = 0;
   for i = 1:n % We iterate over `c`
      tmp = c(i);
      for j = 1:i-1 % We iterate over the relevant elements of `nodes`
          tmp *= x - nodes(j); % We multiply `c(i) * (x - nodes(1)) * (x -nodes(2)) * (x- nodes(3)) * ... * (x - nodes(i -1))
      end
      y += tmp; % We added each product to y
   end
   % Here `y` is as following:
   % c(1) + c(2) * (x - nodes(1)) + c(3) * (x - nodes(1)) * (x - nodes(2)) + ... + c(n) * (x - nodes(1)) * ... * (x - nodes(n - 1))
end
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Answer (score 0):

(I'm sorry this isn't python but I don't know python)

In the case where we didn't have nodes, horner's method works like this:

```
p = c[n]
for i=n-1 .. 1
    p = x*p + c[i]
```

for example for a quadratic (with coeffs a,b,c) this is

```
p = x*(x*a+b)+c
```

Note that if your language supports fma

```
fma(x,y,x) = x*y+z
```

then horner's method can be written

```
p = c[n]
for i=n-1 .. 1
    p = fma( x, p, c[i])
```

When you do have nodes, the change is simple:

```
p = c[n]
for i=n-1 .. 1
    p = (x-nodes[i])*p + c[i]
```

Or, using fma

```
p = c[n]
for i=n-1 .. 1
    p = fma( (x-nodes[i]), p, c[i])
```

For the quadratic above this leads to

```
p = (x-nodes[1]*((x-nodes[2])*a+b)+c
```